# Show results based on one columns results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Apologies not sure of the best way to word this, hopefully you will get the gist!

I am doing a piece to extract a persons wage rates when their basic rate is set to 0.00

Example:

```
Name    | Wage Type  | Amount  
--------+------------+-------
JSmith  | Basic      |  0.00  
JSmith  | Overtime   | 10.00  
JSmith  | Sickness   | 10.00
```

The current code I have is along the lines of

```
select 
    w.forenames, w.surname, ty.description, r.amount
from 
    rolesAndRates r 
left join
    workers w on r.owner = w.person 
left join
    rateTypes ty on r.rate = ty.id
where 
    ty.description = 'basic rate' 
    and amount = 0.00
```

Which results in just the basic rate being returned (for obvious reasons).

However I wish to have all the wage types under the one employee.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Show us the table data giving that result.

Comment: The expected result is that of the post, the table it all comes from is essentially the same but a number of employees some who will have a basic rate > 0.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think/hope this is what you want. 
Return all rates for people who have a zero basic rate.

```
--use CTE to find people with basic of 0.00
with peopleWithZeroBasic as (
    select w.person
    from #rolesAndRates r 
    left join #workers w on r.owner=w.person 
    left join #rateTypes ty on r.rate=ty.id
    where ty.description='basic' and amount=0.00
)

select w.forenames, w.surname, ty.description,r.amount
from #rolesAndRates r 
left join #workers w on r.owner=w.person 
left join #rateTypes ty on r.rate=ty.id
where w.person in (select person from peopleWithZeroBasic)
```

so for the data

```
create table #rolesAndRates (  rate int, amount decimal, owner varchar(20))
create table #workers ( forenames varchar(max), surname varchar(max), person varchar(20) )
create table #rateTypes (id int, description varchar(max))

insert into #rateTypes (id, description) values (1,'basic')
insert into #rateTypes (id, description) values (2,'overtime')
insert into #rateTypes (id, description) values (3,'sickness')

insert into #workers (forenames, surname, person) values ('john', 'smith', 'jsmith')
insert into #workers (forenames, surname, person) values ('jim', 'beam', 'jbeam')

insert into #rolesAndRates (rate, amount, owner) values (1,0.00,'jsmith')
insert into #rolesAndRates (rate, amount, owner) values (2,10.00,'jsmith')
insert into #rolesAndRates (rate, amount, owner) values (3,5.00,'jsmith')

insert into #rolesAndRates (rate, amount, owner) values (1,7.00,'jbeam')
insert into #rolesAndRates (rate, amount, owner) values (2,10.00,'jbeam')
insert into #rolesAndRates (rate, amount, owner) values (3,5.00,'jbeam');
```

it produces the following output:

```
forenames   surname description amount
john    smith   basic   0
john    smith   overtime    10
john    smith   sickness    5
```

i.e. ignores jim beam as he doesn't have a basic rate of zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `in` or `exists`:

```
select w.forenames, w.surname, rt.description, rr.amount
from rolesAndRates rr join
     workers w
     on rr.owner = w.person join
     rateTypes rt
     on rr.rate = rt.id
where exists (select 1
              from rolesAndRates rr2 join
                   rateTypes rt2
                   on rr2.rate = rt2.id
              where rt.description = 'basic rate' and
                    rr.amount = 0.00 and
                    rr2.owner = rr.owner
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to come up with exact syntax as you have not mentioned al lthe tables in question. But something like this is what you need.

```
select w.forenames, w.surname, ty.description,r.amount
from rolesAndRates r left join
     workers w
     on r.owner=w.person left join
     rateTypes ty
     on r.rate=ty.id
where 
w.<name column> in ( select <name column> from rateTypes where
description='basic rate' and amount=0.00)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone so far.. I probably wasn't that clear in my detail, I would like all the wage types displayed when the basic rate is 0.00